# Kotlin - RecyclerView.LayoutManager issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm learning `Kotlin` & Adroid Studio and recently I have stuck on `RecyclerView`.

The problem is that I'm not able to go forward due to error showing on `LayoutManager`.

My little code looks like:

```
 package com.example.julian.recyclerviewapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)

    }
}
```

`LayoutManager` is underlined and tells me that: "

```
Classifier 'LayoutManager' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initalized here".
```

I'm not a advanced programist, rather a newbie and I've been trying to fix this remark but at this moment its beyond my skills.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: it's `val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below:

```
my_recyclerview_id.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

Here `"my_recyclerview_id"` is your `recyclerview` id from your layout XML file.

Answer (score 0):

```
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
<your recyclerview>.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

Or even shorter:

```
<your recyclerview>.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
1st way

```
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
your_recyclerview_id!!.layoutManager = layoutManager
your_recyclerview_id!!.adapter = Your_adapter(applicationContext)
```

2nd way

```
 your_recyclerview_id!!.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
 your_recyclerview_id!!.adapter = Your_adapter(applicationContext);
 your_recyclerview_id!!.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Best of luck with Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

No need to define 'findviewByID' in kotlin...Android understand by default all resource and View element.

you can try it...

Only use this code when you are working on RecycleView in kotlin

```
 rc_all_transaction.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(activity, 
   LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true))
```

here  rc_all_transaction is ID of Recycleview and rest is setting Layout Manager

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Tt should be `RecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)`.
Lower-case `l` and not upper-case `L`.